# Layers messed up

Tags: layers

I opened Blender and continued a project I've been working on.
I was working in layer 4, and when I went back to layer 2 it was all messed up.
I simply followed this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVwfEHtLiyI

picture of layer 1
[image: screen shot of blender]

Comment: Your question says it is a picture of layer 2, but you are on layer 1 in that picture.

Comment: oh yeah, i meant 1 and 2 they look the same:)

Comment: your question is still unclear, what should your layer 1 look like? What was all messed up on layer 2?

Comment: The video should explain that:-) its really hard to explain.

Comment: not all of us want to spend 30 minutes watching an irrelevant tutorial so we can help some random guy :-P

Comment: pretty wierd question

Comment: I think he means the smooth shading on the box.

Comment: Fully understandable, i just cant really explain what the problem is, btw im just helping a friend, i will try to get more information:)

Comment: Is it the strange black/grey streaked shading on the box that is wrong?

Comment: it was supposed to be something else, but it somehow changed itself

Comment: Your doing a fluid sim - do you expect the domain to be shown in wireframe only? You can change your viewport shading to wireframe. Also loosing the fluid sim cache (or going to a frame that hasn't been baked) will cause the water shape to disappear, showing the cube again.